# SEO improvement & tools/checklist for specific location

Tags: wordpress, search-engine, seo

Im not sure if this question is right for on here.....

Im trying to improve SEO for my own website (the location is critical). Its located in a village outside a local town, in which there are many competitors. If somebody searches (village + keyword) its on the first page but im trying to get it on the first page for (local town + other keyword).

Does anybody know of any SEO tools i could use or a general SEO checklist and how to improve for that specific search.

Also im using wordpress as the CMS.
Anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i like to use [All-in-one-SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/)

You can get very specific with the tags, title, keywords, etc for each and every page. or set global keywords, descriptions, etc.

Getting on the front page of a search engine is difficult. Even if you have better keyword saturation on your site than competitors, it will take a while (weeks, months even) for google to index you properly and adjust its ranking for the new site.

My suggestion is keyword density (amount of times a keyword appears on a single page) is the biggest factor to focus on.

Comment: I'll recommend against keyword density in favor of fresh content; that is, a regularly updated blog with relevant posts about your niche, and a strong social presence. Social signals from sites like Facebook, Pinterest, Twitter, etc, are an increasingly important part of a good SEO strategy, and keyword density (ratio of your relevant search terms to the text on a given page) is a rather outdated idea. Sure, it's still important, but not as important as providing value to visitors with interesting, relevant content.

Answer (score -1):

The SEO Checklist for every year is mostly same.

You need to stick to basics and doest try black hat SEO techniques. The details of white hat SEO checklist can be found here, Which is applicable to every location.

http://seoplusplus.com/seo-checklist-every-blogger-should-follow/